# angular - scroll height and document height units

Tags: angular

When the window slides, it can detect the current height, but I don't know the unit of this height. I hope to get the total height(bottom height) by angular.

The height of the `document` is different from the height unit of the `scroll`. How do you convert between the two? Or in what way do you get the common unit?

For example:

```
 import {HostListener,Inject} from "@angular/core";
 import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";

 constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document {}

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 @HostListener("window:scroll", [])onWindowScroll() {
    //.scrollTop
    console.log(this.document.documentElement.scrollTop)
    //.clientHeight
    console.log(this.document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    //.innerHeight
    console.log(window.innerHeight);
 }
```

These three are different.
`document.documentElement.scrollTop` ≠ `document.documentElement.clientHeight` ≠ `window.innerHeight`

Comment: what do you mean by convert? these are separate properties and hence named differently - with definitions present in various locations

Comment: @AIqbalRaj Edited in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this question has nothing to do with Angular, but it is specifically Javascript DOM model.

Second all heights and width are returned in pixels, so there is no question of conversion

now specific to elements asked by you

`document.documentElement.scrollTop` - this property  returns the number of pixels an element's content is scrolled vertically. For more information [refer this url](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp)

`window.innerHeight` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` are same, only difference is IE older browser calles it `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, and modern browswer calles it `window.innerHeight`. Refer this link [for more details](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp)

Comment: Is there any way to get the total height of the scroll?

Comment: Scroll is always attached to an element, most of the time div. So you can get height of corresponding div. I prefer to use  `$('#some_div').height();`, but in case you are not using jquery, please use `document.getElementById('some_div').getBoundingClientRect().height` or `document.getElementById('some_div').clientHeight`

Comment: I tried to use `this.document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height`, its value is closer to `this.document.documentElement.scrollTop`,but `this.document.documentElement.clientHeight` is completely another value.

Comment: Am not sure how you are checking but at element level there are not many variations than mentioned below  ` document.getElementById("some_div").height ` 2) `height() - return the height without padding `
3) `innerHeight() - Returns the height of an element (includes padding)`
4) `outerHeight() - Returns the height of an element (includes padding and border)`

Comment: If you using Chrome, please take help from Developer Tool ( Control + Shift + I ) , you will know which class exactly changing height .  And refer url  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_height.asp
 and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp for height specific knowledge.

Comment: Awesome, this may require some diagrams to help understand where each parameter is covered.

Comment: probably it has more than we can think off. You can start with Elements tab ( first tab in top line ) , then at right side of screen you will find many tabs Styles Computed, etc... for you Style and computed tab will be sufficient and here you can make a search of CSS element you want to debug

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in Angular to get the scroll height

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
WindowScrollEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  console.log("event", window.scrollY);
  
}
```